# Unable to start Kestrel. Failed to bind to address address already in use

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, process

I want to start a .net core application from an API that I created which is also in .Net Core too.

I added `UseUrls()` function to Program.cs file so it will use a port that i want it to use. So heres what it looks my Program.cs of that other module.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:50003")
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            }
            )
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
                options.ValidateScopes = false)
            .Build();
}
```

So when I open CMD where this module where is located and type `dotnet run` it will start running application on `http://localhost:50003`, which is fine because thats the port where I want to start.

But what I need to do, is to start this app from that API. And heres the code that I wrote the command `dotnet run`:

```
public IActionResult RunPackage(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var workingDirectory = 'here goes the path of the directory of this module that i want to start running';

            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processStartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
            processStartInfo.Arguments = "run";
            processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            process.Start();
            var reader = process.StandardOutput;
            var output = reader.ReadToEnd();

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

But when I'm running it, that `output` variable returns an error which it says

```
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:4221: 
address already in use
```

And i dont know why it tries to start the app with `4221` port while it is written in Program.cs to use port `50003`.

So the same command `dotnet run` is working fine if i write manually in CMD and its not working the way it should if i type on my code.

> "Using launch settings from C:\Users\StarTech\Desktop\Actibook Actibook\actibook-backend\ServerCore\TimeFrame.Actibook.WebService\wwwroot\Packages\2018-6-Friday031203SampleConverter\Properties\launchSettings.json...\r\ncrit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]\r\n      Unable to start Kestrel.\r\nSystem.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:4221: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.AddressInUseException: Error -4091 EADDRINUSE address already in use ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4091 EADDRINUSE address already in use\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.LibuvFunctions.ThrowError(Int32 statusCode)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.LibuvFunctions.tcp_getsockname(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32& namelen)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.GetSockIPEndPoint()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.ListenTcp(Boolean useFileHandle)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.CreateListenSocket()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.<>c.b__8_0(Listener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.CallbackAdapter`1.<>c.<.cctor>b__3_1(Object callback, Object state)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.DoPostWork()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.ListenerPrimary.<StartAsync>d__15.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.LibuvTransport.<BindAsync>d__20.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.LibuvTransport.<BindAsync>d__20.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1.<g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.d__23`1.MoveNext()\r\n"

launchSettings.json contanins:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60924/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "SampleConverter": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60925/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably you see the output that has something to do with this file - " C:\Users\StarTech\Desktop\...\Properties\launchSettings.json". What's its content?

Comment: `dotnet run` is invalid for deployment (as it is for development only). You should publish the binaries via `dotnet publish` and use `dotnet` to launch the entry assembly directly.

Comment: @KirylZ just added code of that file here. But there are just some basic configs about launching. Bu the problem is that even that here says url: `localhost:60925` and 60924, that code that I added in Program.cs should overwrite it. P.s. When I start from the code, it does not even bind these port written here.

Comment: @LexLi I tried writing `dotnet publish`, then went to publish directory and used `dotnet ApplicationName.dll` but still the same.

Comment: @ErtanHasani Have you tried to narrow down the process that listens on 4221? like via netstat?

Comment: @KirylZ yep, but the problem is that I do need a static IP, thats why I'm giving it in Program.cs. Not an IP that app will randomly generate it.

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this work?  It's how my API Was set up a while ago...

```
  public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
            options=>
            {                    
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 50003);
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            })
        )
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
            options.ValidateScopes = false)
        .Build();
```

Comment: No the problem is that when i type on CMD `dotnet run` it works perfectly and it binds that IP that i write, but when i try to run it from API it binds another ip. I also tried writing like you and still the same.

Comment: so I see...  Why launch it separately like that and not just add the controllers etc. to the other API? seems that would be a bit cleaner (not to mention far easier to debug)

Comment: Thats because I have some microservices which are dynamically added and removed. So when I add a new .dll then I have to start it and stop it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run the following in visual studio command prompt.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

if you still face the issue, try

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

and then retry this command

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 1):

I also met the error like you and that because I opened 2 terminals and "dotnet watch run" both of them. To solve it, just Ctrl+C to stop the terminal and "dotnet watch run" again in 1 terminal.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in a blazor server project, after delete folder `AppData`.

Solved change target start project in `visual studio`. Dont know if best way but I had trying lot things without success...

[image]